# Why does fmt.Printf("%x", 'ᚵ') ~> 16b5, while fmt.Printf("%x", "ᚵ") ~> e19ab5?

Tags: go, utf-8, string-formatting

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("%c, %x, %x", 'ᚵ', 'ᚵ', "ᚵ")
}
```

Outputs:

```
ᚵ, 16b5, e19ab5
```

https://play.golang.org/p/_Bs7JcdOfO

Comment: Figured it out after I had the question already written. May just answer it as well...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because each does a different thing. Both format the argument as a hexadecimal number, but each views the argument differently.

`fmt.Printf("%x", 'ᚵ')` prints a single unicode character (a rune, if you will), as a 32 bit integer (int32).

`fmt.Printf("%x", "ᚵ")` prints a string (individual bytes of a string) as 8 bit integers (uint8). The rune is encoded on three bytes when utf-8 encoding is used. That is a reason why there is six hexadecimal digits (two for each byte).

To study printing of a string in detail, start at function `fmtString` in file `fmt/print.go`.

```
func (p *pp) fmtString(v string, verb rune) {
```

Comment: The language you used is a bit confusing: with single quotes it prints the Unicode *codepoint* (U+16B5). A codepoint is a number assigned by the unicode consortium together with a description of what this should represent. It *doesn't* say how this should be represented in a text file.
With double quotes it prints the raw bytes in the UTF-8 encoded string. The bytes in UTF-8 don't directly align in 8-bit bytes, so there is no apparent correspondence if you look at just the hex characters. Wikipedia has a [useful example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Examples) on how this works.

Comment: Sounds better. Post that as an answer and I'll accept it ;)